# Choose the selected value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a dropdownbox with some values. When a user selects a value, and hits save, then I want to get that selected value in the C# code.

Here is my code:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult AddAdmin(AdminViewModel model)
 {           
     if(ModelState.IsValid) 
     {
         List<Roles> list = col.Roles.ToList();
         model.Roles = col.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
         {
             Value = x.RoleName,
             Text = "Choose a role...",
         }).ToList();

         var admin = new Admin()
         {
             FirstName = model.FirstName,
             LastName = model.LastName,
             MemberEmail = model.MemberEmail,
             RoleName = list.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToString()
          };
          DBContext.Admin.Add(admin);
          DBContext.SaveChanges();
     }
     return View(model);
 }
```

So what I want is the value:

```
Value = x.RoleName  (Let's just say the value is "Admin")
```

Right now I am trying to select it like this:

```
RoleName = list.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToString()
```

But what I get in the database is this:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectListIterator`2[AuthSys.Models.Roles,System.String]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `list.Select(x => x.RoleName)` returns a collection of rolenames.... and when you do `ToString()` on it returns the typename of that collection. If you want only a single role name then you should do `list.Where(x => x.RoleName == "Admin").Select(x => x.RoleName).FirstOrDefault()`;

Comment: Try this => `RoleName = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleName == "Admin");`

Comment: Forget the admin, that was just a silly example. I will not know what value the user has selected, it could be any value. I just want to know what that value is, and save it to the database. I don't think FirstOrDefault() will do, as it will just give me the first value in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddAdmin(AdminViewModel model)
{           
   if(ModelState.IsValid) 
   {
      List<Roles> list = new List<Roles>(col.Roles.ToList());
      model.Roles = col.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = x.RoleName,
                Text = "Choose a role...",

            }).ToList();

     var admin = new Admin()
     {
        FirstName = model.FirstName,
        LastName = model.LastName,
        MemberEmail = model.MemberEmail,
        //// If RoleName column is an type of VarChar then you are doing wrong here.
        // RoleName = list.Select(x => x.RoleName).ToString();

        //// try static string of role.
        RoleName = "Admin"
        or
        RoleName = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleName == model.[RoleNameFieldFromModel])?.RoleName;
     };

     DBContext.Admin.Add(admin);
     DBContext.SaveChanges();
   }
  return View(model);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to return what match RoleName from Role object as string

```
RoleName = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.RoleName == "Admin")?.RoleName;
```

It is also a good idea to check against null in your view so it does not break